# Ignore commas in string

Tags: c, string

I have the following code:

```
char dump[50];
char genre[50];
char line[300] = "Can't Help Falling in Love, Michael Buble, Pop";
sscanf(line, "%s %s %s", dump, dump, genre);
```

The character array "line" will change every time the program runs with the `names, artist` and `genre` of a different song. How can I make everything up to the comma one string, so that when `sscanf` runs, the array `"genre"` holds the words `"Pop"`? Right now it holds `"Falling"` obviously since it's the third word.

Thanks

Comment: Why not search for the position of "," in the string and use that for substring operations?

Comment: I'm rather new to C so I'm not exactly sure what that does but i'll go check it out. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    char genre[50];
    char line[300] = "Can't Help Falling in Love, Michael Buble, Pop";
    sscanf(line, "%*[^,], %*[^,], %s", genre);
    printf("%s", genre);//display genre
```

name and artist need

```
    char name[50];
    char artist[50];
    char genre[50];
    char line[300] = "Can't Help Falling in Love, Michael Buble, Pop";
    sscanf(line, "%[^,], %[^,], %s", name, artist, genre);
    printf("name: %s\n", name);
    printf("artist: %s\n", artist);
    printf("genre: %s\n", genre);
```

Comment: Mind explaining what the * do?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. I get nothing outputted to the terminal.

Comment: not likely to see anything printed in the terminal without a puts or printf in there

Comment: Oops. I had my printf...just after a break in my loop. *facepalm* thanks :D

Comment: Is there a way I can still extract the artist and song name with this method? (Yeah, I realize there both assigned to the same array but I'm going to change that.)

Answer (score 2):

I think [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) is what you are looking for. See the link for description and sample code.

From this few lines, You can see how it works:

```
char line[300] = "Can't Help Falling in Love, Michael Buble, Pop";
dump = strtok(line,",");
dump = strtok(NULL,",");
genre = strtok(NULL,",");
```

There is maybe a chance that a song title contains a comma. In that case You should modify a little the while loop on the linked page. With that, You can easily find the substring following the last comma.

Comment: Ok. I looked those up a while back in regards to this issue but I a hard time understanding how I would apply it to this situation. Any chance you could give me some pointers?

Comment: Be careful with `strtok`. It modifies the string that it operates on, so you might need to make a separate copy of it -- and you can't operate directly on a string literal with it.

Comment: Well in the actual program I'm grabbing the string from a text file so that shouldn't be a problem.